# Send data to view in parent controller class

Tags: grails, view, controller

image controller X and controller Y. Both (X and Y) extends controller A. Controller A has some common logic (check if user is logged etc.).

Can i in controller A (in method beforeInterceptor) set some data to view (so this data will be accessible in all method of controller X and Y).
(for example, in controller A in beforeInterceptor get data for MENU - MENU is used in all views for every methods in controller X / Y)

Or such a problem should be resolved in other way ?

thank your for your helo

Comment: Problem solved ... i should use AFTER INTERCEPTOR where is model map (so i can add to it what i need)

Answer (score 1):

First for security purposes I would rely on [Spring Security Plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/spring-security-core) rather than your hand roll security. It makes your life a lot easier as your application grow. Its powerful, safe, and its pretty simple to implement.

There are many approaches to grab menu data from `server`. You can probably do what you said with interceptors, or a filter and inject it into each view/response, or store/cache it in a `session`. I think the `session` is more efficient as you don't have to return menu items each time. Even if you don't want to use session for sure cache the data, if they are static.

If you want to keep those data in your controller I would create a `Private` method that returns the values. This prevents it to act as an action.  A better approach is have n a service with [cacheable](http://grails.org/plugin/cache) method and returns menu items. Then you can transfer that to the views through one of the able approaches.